# If Coulomb and Esu have different dimensions, why can we convert simply by 1C= 3*10e9 esu?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, coulombs-law, unit-conversion

I was always told in school we cannot convert an apple into a potato, so we have to have the same dimensions on both sides. 
When converting coulomb to esu, we do not seem to bother with dimensions. Why is it still possible?

Comment: One can, however, find a correspondence between coulombs and statcoulombs in different contexts [Statcoulomb - General incompatibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statcoulomb#General_incompatibility)

Answer (score 2):

An important point here is that you don't *just* convert from Coulombs to ESU. You *also* change the units of various constants that appear in the expressions of electromagnetism.

The most obvious example is, Coulomb's Law
$$\begin{align*}
F_{SI} &= \left (8,99 \times 10^9 \,\mathrm{N \, m^2/C^2}\right)
\frac{q_{1, C} \, q_{2, C}}{r^2} \\
F_{guass} &= \left (1 \,\mathrm{dimensionless} \right)
\frac{q_{1,ESU} \, q_{2,ESU}}{r^2}  \,.
\end{align*}$$

Similarly in Gauss's Law the factor of $1/\epsilon_0$ (which is dimensional) that appears in SI units must also be converted to a $4\pi$ (dimensionless) in Gaussian units.

The upshot is that the statement 
$$ 1\,\mathrm{C} = 2997924580 \,\mathrm{ESU} \, \tag{!}$$
isn't *really* an equality, but is one step in a recipe for converting between different systems of units.

Comment: Is there a proper formula for conversion, including dimensions? I cannot do it, because i cannot keep dimensions of the different systems on different sides of the equation. Probably, it is as if I wanted to convert from meter to seconds - impossible. (?) Although, obviously it IS possible.

Comment: I do not mean one equation, but a way of derivating one from the other. Including dimensions.